# Do I have to tell Keras my input dimensions when creating the Input layer?

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using the functional API to create an input layer, feed that into a time-distributed layer, and then feed that into an LSTM. As of now, it looks something like this

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(100,10,20))
layer_2 = TimeDistributed(SomeLayer(params))(input_layer)
```

My issue is that I'd like to feed time sequences of various lengths into my neural net, and not just sequences of a hundred time steps.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add variable number of time steps , you can pad the sequences to length = max time steps

```
data_array=sequence.pad_sequences(data_array,maxlen=max_timesteps)
```

**EDIT:**
    I found this answer which might be useful. You just have to keep the time steps same in a batch. They can vary across the batches

[Training an RNN with examples of different lengths in Keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras)

Comment: What if I don't know the maxlen?

Comment: You may set one . Anyways,imho , your model will also dictate the max time steps. It wont work efficiently with any timesteps